# Microsoft Graph API inaccurate error message

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to add users in an Azure AD B2C using the Microsoft Graph API. My code works just fine when I add a User, but I tried to add it a second time with the same info given to the API (mail, names, etc...) and expected an error like

> User already exists

or something similar.

My API call is done like this :

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User()
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                Mail = "example@example.onmicrosoft.com",
                MailNickname = "example",
                UserPrincipalName = "example@example.onmicrosoft.com",
                Surname = "TEST",
                DisplayName = "test",
                GivenName = "TEST test",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = "tmpPwd"
                }
            });
```

Keeping in mind that my first call correctly add the user to the AD, why the API would return me this message :

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : 'Code: Request_BadRequest
> Message: One or more properties contains invalid values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, what is the question? Or do you just not like the way that the exception is formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) Create the user using the below property without `mail` .so that when a user has already existed then you will get the error as below

```
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already exists.
```

code:

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User()
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
               
                MailNickname = "example",
                UserPrincipalName = "example665@XX.live",
                Surname = "TEST",
                DisplayName = "test",
                GivenName = "TEST test",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = "password@1234"
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        }
```

Using additional property may change the error context as you are receiving currently